# Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x grid system only without the rest?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Might seem like a strange question but I'm working on a legacy system and I can't mess with any fonts or look and feel things. I really miss bootstrap's convenient grid layout system. I'm wondering if anyone has already gone to the trouble of publishing a stripped down CSS for only the grid part of the boostrap scaffolding.

Comment: You could just @import the .less files you need, or start with the bootstrap.less file and comment out the ones you don't need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate [custom build](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and include only grid rules